# A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, casting, listbox, equality

I'm getting this exception when binding the ItemsSource of a ListBox  to an `ObservableCollection<object>`.

The collection is populated with a mix of {DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs, EventEntry}

I peeked `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs` and found:

```
public struct DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
{
    ...
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals((DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)obj); <- huge cast right here?
    }
}
```

Code for EventEntry:

```
public class EventEntry
{
    public EventEntry(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

As I read the peeked code it is designed to explode.

Is this right?

Comment: Derive from DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs and override Equals? Or don't use it at all and use your own class instead?

Comment: @Clemens yeah, time for a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed bug, repro:

```
[Test]
public void Repro()
{
    var args = new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(UIElement.IsEnabledProperty, false, true);
    Assert.Throws<InvalidCastException>(() => args.Equals(1));
}
```

[Confirmed bug in the implementation: (below code is from reference source)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/src/Base/System/Windows/DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.cs#274)

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return Equals((DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)obj);
}
```

[Filed a bug on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/870970/dependencypropertychangedeventargs-equals-object-o-throws-invalidcastexception)

Comment: It is not meant as an answer, more info. Should make it wiki if I knew how to.